# Prolog code gives two different results

Tags: list, prolog

So I'm making this code where there's a function that receives 2 arguments and tells if one of them is not a list.

The code is the following:

```
/*** List Check ***/
islist(L) :- L == [], !.
islist(L) :- nonvar(L), aux_list(L).
aux_list([_|_]).

/*** Double List Check ***/
double_check(L, L1) :- \+islist(L) -> write("List 1 invalid"); 
    \+islist(L1)-> write("List 2`invalid"); write("Success").
```

It shuold be working. [Online](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) the code does exactly what I want it to. But on the Prolog console of my computer it gives a completely different answer:

```
?- double_check(a, [a]).
[76,105,115,116,97,32,49,32,105,110,118,97,108,105,100,97] 
true.
```

example. I have NO IDEA where that list came from. Can someone tell me my error and help me fix it please? Thank you all!

Comment: My bad, I had the code written in portuguese and translated it. I forgot that though. Thank you for noticing! Edited.

Comment: Sorry again. Forgot to delete the "a". I haven't slept in a long time, give me a break guys lol jk. Thanks for the note. It is now corrected!

Comment: it's all good. we know how it is :)

Comment: @repeat I am currently wearing the updated version. The newest. Both on Linux and Windows. Same mistake on both. Does it give you the same mistake or is it just my computer?

Comment: @lispHK01 I'm really mad though... I can't figure out what's going on... It doesn't recognize the condition for some reason and returns a strange list. But on the other hand, it works online... I really don't know...

Comment: In Prolog, `"abc"` represents a *list* of character codes for `a`, `b`, and `c`. So `write("List 2`invalid")` will write the list, `[76,105,115,116,97,32,49,32,105,110,118,97,108,105,100,97]`, which is the list of character codes for `"List 2 invalid"`.. If you want to print `abc` using `write`, you write it as an atom, `write('abc')` with single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: @lurker OMG... I can't believe I didn't see it... THANK YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix: Use `format/2` instead of `write/1`!
For more information on the built-in predicate `format/2`, [click here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2).

```
$ swipl --traditional
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.37) [...]

?- write("abc").
[97,98,99]                                % output by write/1 via side-effect
true.                                     % truth value of query (success)

?- format('~s',["abc"]).
abc                                       % output by format/2 via side-effect
true.                                     % truth value (success)
```

However with different command line arguments:

```
$ swipl 
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.37) [...]

?- write("abc").
abc
true.

?- format('~s',["abc"]).
abc
true.
```

Even though it may seem like a nuisance, I recommend using command-line option `--traditional` for SWI-Prolog, in combination with `format/2` instead of `write/1`. **Preserve [portability](/questions/tagged/portability)!**

Comment: I see... I have never used or heard about the format function. Could it be because of that? Is my function printing without format? If so, how can I make it print well?

Edit: I now believe that is my problem! I tried to print an "ola" and it printed a list. Please help me fix this!

Comment: But... Why is this happening? Did I messed up somewhere with the Prolog libraries? Or it's setup/definitions?

Comment: Well, thank you so much for the help, sir, I really apreciate it! Marked as accepted! If it isn't asking too much, can you please help me printing it well, by giving me the first argument of `format/2`?

Comment: Solved!Thank you so much! Really apreciate it!